# What is the best method to prevent users from accessing data that can only be obtained by being logged in?

Tags: php, authentication, session-variables

I am using a publicly made login to test and modify, however no matter what I do when a user logs out, they are able to log right back in by using the back button in their browser, refresh the page, and still be logged in. What is the best way to prevent this? I am new to PHP and am in the process of learning. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You can find all of the files necessary here: https://github.com/devplanete/php-login-advanced.

You can also test it here: http://www.php-login.net/demo3.html

Comment: Make sure you unset all cookies and sessions related to users on logout.

Comment: that wasn't the issue, but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there are only 2 possibilities that are wrong.
First you do not delete the cookies and the sessions properly which makes the user is not logged out.

Secondly, you don't check on the page they try to access if the user is logged or not.

Update: As said above in the comments, you need to separate your login form treatment from the index page if you want not the user to be able to re log again from the logout page by pressing back key.
Your template is currently index.php => index.php login treatment then displaying
You need to do index.php => login.php login treatment => redirect back to index.php

Comment: But I did, did you look at the files?

Comment: Yes, the edit.php file is accessible after the logout process ? And you have exactly the same files ? Like index.php too ?

Comment: Exact same everything except the config.php. From what I can tell it looks like the session is being destroyed and the cookie is set to expire/delete.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are on the edit.php then you logout and when going back (back to edit.php) and then refresh you can see edit.php again?

Comment: index.php form action => login.php (do the login process here) => redirect to index.php. What you are currently doing is index.php => login process (index.php) => index.php

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: any other way of that? making that the user can't log back when pressing the back button on your current website? not really. and the current architecture is not really advised, you really should separate it.

Comment: Thanks to you I got it working properly. I did as you suggested and separated the views. If you would please edit out the link to my website in your comment, and I will accept your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Had to suppress it